# Using Temperature sensor arduino to trip off an ac device

Tags: relay

Using Temperation through arduino to trip off an ac device?

Comment: My hovercraft is full of eels.

Comment: I assume that what you are trying to ask is something like: "How can I use a temperature sensor to control an AC (mains) powered device with an Arduino?" It really helps if you can state a clear question. Perhaps you could edit the post to add some detail and clearly state your question. Also as a new user it encourages people responding to you if you follow up on comments quickly.

Comment: @Majenko, I understand the frustration that comes with fuzzy questions, but in the long run I think we do better if we can offer constructive advice on how to ask good questions. Someday I'm going to get around to writing some Text Expander snippets so that I can make my suggestions when I'm in a good place and then reuse them :-)

Comment: Welcome to Arduino Stack Exchange. We hope you find this site useful. Please read [How to ask a good question](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question as it stands is very unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are lots and lots of project descriptions similar to yours (if I guesstimate) on the web. Google is your friend.

Here is one [link](http://makezine.com/2014/03/28/arduino-controlled-tec-coolingheating-system-for-beer-fermentation/) to an interesting project - if you are interested in brewing beer.

Cheers!

Comment: Nice project, Mikael. And @user16651 - these are the sort of details you should include in the question. For example, are you attempting to brew beer? Or not? Every bit of information helps get a better answer.